# EF6 slow query using First or FirstOrDefault

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a very strange problem (at least for me!).

I have an EF6 entity which has multiple tables and views, one of the views uses a join to to pull relevant data from other views for display.  When I run the simple query in SSMS the response time is less than a second

```
select * 
from WorkOrderRecord 
where id = 1
```

This is where it gets weird, in my app the following code take 10+ seconds:

```
using (var db = new WorkOrderEntities())
{
    var data = db.WorkOrderRecords.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == id).;
    return data;
}
```

but this takes less than a second:

```
using (var db = new WorkOrderEntities())
{
    var data = db.WorkOrderRecords.Where(a => a.id == id).ToList();
    return data.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I've tried removing the view from `WorkOrderEntities` and re-adding, I have rebuilt the indexes on SQL Server, rebuilt the statistics.  No real change.

The SQL code generated by FirstOrDefault looks like this

```
SELECT TOP (1)      
    Extent1.---every single column 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [WorkOrderRecord].--every single column
     FROM 
         [dbo].[WorkOrderRecord] AS [WorkOrderRecord]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
    [Extent1].[id] = 24000
```

The SQL code for `WHERE` is basically the same code but without the `TOP (1)`.

Why such a performance difference, I assume this is a SQL thing and not an EF6 thing, since I can sort of reproduce it in SSMS. I have delete all the statistics and indexes, recreated them, checked the joins, SQL profiler is no help, what should I try next?

Comment: If you're really curious, compare the query plans for each. Is there an index/key on `id`? The one with `TOP` might be doing some kind of implicit ordering, where the other doesn't.

Comment: how many rows do you have? have you tried to capture the query using SQL Profiler? does the `id` is a primary key? *I assume this is a SQL thing and not an EF6 thing, since I can sort of reproduce it in SSMS.* this hints something wrong on SQL Server.. perhaps checking [DBA Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) can help.

Comment: This smells very much like a "EF thing" really. The generated SQL is simply poor and will defeat many optimization techniques of SQL Server.

Comment: Yes there is an index, and its the primary key.  There are about 25K rows in one table 10K in another and less than 1000 in the 3rd.